# Less control with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm still learning AngularJS, but I'm not sure if having less control (via javascript) as I read is a good thing. I mean, everything is done via bindings through HTML code / attributes. 
How can I access $rootScope , or any of the services other than having them injected to my controllers via 'low level' javascript code?
angular global variable doesn't hold much when logged to the console. What else to use to discover possible methods accessable via javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this will be closed as opinion based but here is my opinion:

Angular does not remove your ability to control the page via javascript.  Instead it isolates that code that manipulates the DOM.  The learning curve for angular is a little like a roller coaster, in that you feel differently about the framework after learning a new piece.  I felt really great after learning how templates and controllers worked but then felt low after seeing the limitations and complexities it created only to feel really great when I learned about Directives and how to manipulate the DOM through them.  Six months into it, I am comfortable with Angular and would never go back to all the boilerplate of straight JQuery/javascript.

An important thing to keep in mind.  Angular is not a UI library but rather a way of organizing your development files. There are many integration libraries of well known UI frameworks into angular Directives but by far the most popular is Twitter Bootstrap.

This blog post really nailed it: https://coderwall.com/p/3qclqg